# Is the default behaviour for NSManagedObjectContext save() method a blocking method?

Tags: core-data, swift2, nsmanagedobjectcontext

To be very specific: If I get the managed object context from the app delegate and do not set any parameters on it, what happens when running inserts, updates followed by save()?

Does the app block on save() until done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `save` method blocks. It's not even a default-- that's how it is, always. Does't matter if the context came from the app delegate or somewhere else, `save` is a synchronous method.

Comment: So what would be the case if I action a save via a background thread (I.e. to complete later) and a save in the main thread to complete now? I have a scenario where it looks as if CoreData transaction does not complete before table.reload() starts and the transaction is in the main thread...

Comment: If you're saving on two threads, you have no guarantee about which one completes first-- unless you're ensuring it by the use of `performBlock`, or GCD, or some other operation queueing system. It sounds like you need to ask a different question with more detail about your specific issue.

Comment: Surely if the save is a blocking method, then whether or not I have one transaction in the background and one on main thread, as long as the one on the main thread is before table.reload() the table.reload() should wait for the transaction on the main thread to complete. No?

Comment: Saving is a blocking, synchronous method, but multithreading can cause complex problems with any API. It's impossible to answer in any more detail without **lots** more information about your specific app and the issue you're facing.

Comment: point taken. I am running tests now having swapped the calls (moved the background thread till after table.reload() ). I am hoping that this will solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This what it came down to:
Normally, when I create an object, I only set the main key (properties that don't change through the lifecycle of the object) on creation. I then use an update method to complete the creation. In this particular case, I changed one property on the server from 'creational' property to 'updateable' property, but I missed it in the app. So the app was deleting the objects only to have the server create them again a bit later...